# Start slideshow with delay

Tags: javascript

I integrated a slider on my brothers website. He wants some preloading, so the the first image of the slide lasts longer than the rest, so the slider can load all images while the first image shows. Do you have any ideas how to delay just the first slide? I tried to find something inside the Javascript file but I dont think its a good Idea for me to work in the source.

Link: http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/anna-bederke-actor/

Thank you!

Comment: Post some of your code if possible, jsfiddle link would be best :D

Answer (score 0):

Initially when you start set auto to 0 so it doesn't auto change.

Then after a delay (use `setTimeout()`) set auto to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you know the number of images should be loaded. then you can set a counter and trigger auto change event;

```
var counter = 0;
$(".class-of-images-should-be-loaded").bind("load",function(){
    counter++;
    if(counter == n){         //n - number of images
        //trigger your event
    }
}
```

put a single class to all of the images and use it as the selector.

you can use "settimeout" either but if the connection is very slow, there might be unloaded images in slideshow.

*i used jQuery because you have jQuery library in your web page